# Do all properties need to be present on an object data property in vue?

Tags: vue.js

Say I start out like this:

```
data() {
    return {
        user: {}
    }
}
```

And then later on... I make an API call:

```
let response = await this.axios.get("/api/users/1.json");
this.user = response.data
```

Is this the proper way to assign the data from my API call to `this.user`?

Do all of the properties of `user` need to be defined first?

Comment: If you replace `user` with a new object (as you do in the example) then Vue will apply reactivity to that object. You don't need to define the same fields on the original value, that's irrelevant so long as the `user` property itself is defined in `data`. Just having `user: null` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to declare all properties of `user`. Just having `user` in the data with any value different from `undefined` will suffice.

When the property is in the `data`, Vue will replace it with a `get`ter and a `set`ter. When you do:

```
this.user = newValue;
```

You are actually calling a setter that will map all properties of the `newValue` into getters themselves.

In the official docs, you can find more info on the [**Reactivity in Depth**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) page.

Have a look below. Check the demo and the explanation in the image that shows the object that was created (and printed in the console).

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    other: null,
    user: null
  },
  mounted() {
    this.user = {
      name: 'bob',
      age: 10
    }
  }
})
console.dir(app)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ other }}</p>
  <p>{{ user }}</p>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No you dont need to put properties in it, you can do it like this. You create a method and make a axios inside it:

```
 data() {
   return {
       user: {}
    }
  },
 methods: {
    axiosCall: function (){
                  axios.get("/api/users/1.json").then(response =>{
                      this.user = response.data
                  })
               }
 }
```